# TypeError: sheet.getAs() is not a function when trying to send Google Sheets as PDF attachments via Google Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, pdf-generation

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to send a Google Sheet as a PDF attachment via email. To do this, I'm using the getAs() method to convert the Sheet to a PDF, which can then be attached to an email. However, when I run my script, I'm encountering a TypeError that says "sheet.getAs() is not a function".

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
function dailyOnHandReport() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1axXcJKSawmrlLJYd1YepZZX-3hub7SCAbrE8Su3thMc").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var pdf = sheet.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var message = {
    to: "starfire3d@gmail.com",
    subject: "Daily On Hand Sheet",
    body: "Here's our On Hands for today /n/nHave a great eveing!.",
    attachments: [pdf]
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

I've also tried using the getBlob() method instead of getAs(), but that resulted in a different TypeError that says "sheet.getBlob() is not a function". It seems like neither method is working as expected, and I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

I've asked for help and have been trying different solutions, but so far none of them have worked.

---

Here is the updated code I'm working with:

```
function dailyOnHandReport() {
  var spreadsheetId = "1axXcJKSawmrlLJYd1YepZZX-3hub7SCAbrE8Su3thMc";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
  var message = {
    to: "starfire3d@gmail.com", // Please set your email address.
    subject: "Daily On Hand Sheet",
    body: "Here's our On Hands for today. \n\nHave a great evening!.",
    attachments: [pdf]
  };
  Logger.log("Message: " + JSON.stringify(message));
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class Sheet has no method of `getAs`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. When you want to export a specific sheet in a PDF format, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function dailyOnHandReport() {
  var spreadsheetId = "1axXcJKSawmrlLJYd1YepZZX-3hub7SCAbrE8Su3thMc";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
  var message = {
    to: "###", // Please set your email address.
    subject: "Daily On Hand Sheet",
    body: "Here's our On Hands for today /n/nHave a great eveing!.",
    attachments: [pdf]
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

If your Spreadsheet has only one sheet of "Sheet1", how about the following modification?

```js
function dailyOnHandReport() {
  var spreadsheetId = "1axXcJKSawmrlLJYd1YepZZX-3hub7SCAbrE8Su3thMc";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var pdf = ss.getBlob();
  var message = {
    to: "###", // Please set your email address.
    subject: "Daily On Hand Sheet",
    body: "Here's our On Hands for today /n/nHave a great eveing!.",
    attachments: [pdf]
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

- When a blob is retrieved from Google Docs files (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides), the mimeType is automatically changed to `application/pdf`. By this, `getBlob` can be used.

If you want to export the specific sheets, how about the following modification?

```js
function dailyOnHandReport() {
  var exportSheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet3",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to export.

  var spreadsheetId = "1axXcJKSawmrlLJYd1YepZZX-3hub7SCAbrE8Su3thMc";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(s => {
    if (exportSheets.includes(s.getSheetName())) {
      s.showSheet();
    } else {
      s.hideSheet();
    }
  });
  var pdf = ss.getBlob();
  var message = {
    to: "###", // Please set your email address.
    subject: "Daily On Hand Sheet",
    body: "Here's our On Hands for today /n/nHave a great eveing!.",
    attachments: [pdf]
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  sheets.forEach(s => s.showSheet());
}
```

#### References:

- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [getBlob() of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getblob)

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much. However, now I can't seem to find the email Apps Script sent to me. I've used both the first and second script you modified and searched my spam, drafts, sent, all my has: attachment. I don't think it made it to my inbox. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @david mcgovern Thank you for replying. About `However, now I can't seem to find the email Apps Script sent to me.` and `I don't think it made it to my inbox.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested this modified script, no error occurs and I can get the email with the attachment file. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @david mcgovern By the way, in my proposed script, `to: "###"` is used for hiding the email address. When you test my script, please replace `###` with your email address and test it. Please be careful about this. When I modified `###` to my email address and test the script, I can get an email. If you have no email, please check whether the email could be correctly put in your mail server.

Comment: Sorry to took me a bit to get back to you, and thanks for all the help so far. The script seems to be executing properly but I'm still not able to find the email in my inbox and it seems there is no attachment. I've checked everywhere in my email and triple checked that my email address is correct. I've also updated the original question with my current code. I hope this all makes sense, this is my first time using stack overflow.

Comment: @david mcgovern Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I could know that you used my 1st script. Unfortunately, when I tested my 1st script, no error occurs. I can confirm the email. I cannot replicate your situation of `but I'm still not able to find the email in my inbox and it seems there is no attachment.`. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I figured it out! Turns out the script was running just fine, somehow I had a bunch of filters set up to move things directly to my trash. Got rid of all those useless filters and It works just fine now. Thanks again for all the help and for a great first experience using stack overflow!